# exec(gencat) failed (No such file or directory)

Tags: operating-system, minix

I'm trying to compile the source code of Minix 3.3.0 OS and I got troubles as following.

```
    make[5]: exec(gencat) failed (No such file or directory)
    *** Error code 1

    Stop.
    make[5]: stopped in /usr/src/lib/libc
    *** Error code 1

    Stop.
    make[4]: stopped in /usr/src/lib/libc
    *** Error code 1

    Stop.
    make[3]: stopped in /usr/src/lib
    *** Error code 1

    Stop.
    make[2]: stopped in /usr/src/lib
    *** Error code 1

    Stop.
    make[1]: stopped in /usr/src
    *** Error code 1

    Stop.
    make: stopped in /usr/src
    #
```

I and I ran this command on my VM of Minix3:

```
    git clone git://git.minix3.org/minix src
```

And then I try to compile it by this command:

```
    cd src
    make build
```

And it failed with problems above. It seems like lacking of some files.
Bus how could it happen after I download the code from the official web?
This question has troubled me for a few days and I can't solve it.
Could someone do me a favour?